# android regular expression replace bug

Tags: java, android, regex

A very odd behavior on the part of the Android java regex functions:

I am trying to replace "`<file_info.*>`" in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file_info domain_id="ac-demo" language="en" os="androidtab" version="11" >
     <id string_name="app_name">MobilityPlus</id>
    <!-- general buttons text -->
......
```

Calling: `String.replaceAll( "<file_info.*>", "<resources>" );`
And I get only the **replaced** part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
```

And the rest is **Cropped!! WHY???** I need the whole string returned and only the searched part replaced.
Using at least 2 online regex testers and got exactly what I wanted, but in Android/Java it won't.

**COULD THIS MEAN BUG? In GOOGLE CODE??**

Any recommendations on how to go around this issue will be most appreciated!
Thanks!

(Note: I tried using both String.replaceAll() and Pattern+Matcher and both yield the same results. with multiple lines flag and without, and even after removing all `\t` `\r` `\n`... characters)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but I'm pretty confident that a greedy regular expression isn't going to do whatever it is. You really need to be parsing the XML.

Comment: Why do hard work (xml parsing, bla bla bla...) when you can do the job in 3 lines? this was just the sort of thing I was trying to accomplish. And it seems that the regex Android API is indeed non-standard, or at least different (no real standard I know..) from the Java standard. The problem with this, is that you can't us e the abundance of online regex testers out there, that would otherwise fit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try non-greedy quantifier with `DOTALL`:

```
String.replaceAll( "(?s)<file_info.*?>", "<resources>" );
```

Though I should caution you against parsing/manipulating `XML` using regex.

Comment: This seems like the best answer because of the greediness :) Still, with my poor knowledge of regex, I don't understand why google didn't go with the java/perl standard.. or this is a flag?

Comment: I believe Java regex will also behave same way. Another way to write above is `String.replaceAll( "(?s)<file_info[^>]*>", "<resources>" );`

Comment: You can check [link](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and see that the simple form "<file_info.*>" works without any issue. Same with any other online regex tester. Is this a java issue? I usually work with Qt/C++ which is more compatible with Perl/standard RegEx, So I might be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

MULTILINE mode is irrelevant, but it sounds like you have DOTALL mode set.  That allows the `.` to match line separator characters (`\n`, `\r`, etc.).  You're actually **replacing** everything from the first occurrence of `<file_info` to the last occurrence of `>` in the document.

But you can't count on those or any other whitespace characters being present in XML; they're only there to make it easier for us wetware types to read it.  If you want to replace just the one tag, you should use a negated character class, like so:

```
s = s.replaceAll( "<file_info[^>]*>", "<resources>" );
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be the "greediness" thing (not a big reg-ex pro myself...). But good to know how to set DOTALL straight in the regex